# Spring tests skipped when run with maven

Tags: spring, unit-testing, maven, testing, junit

I'm trying to run JUnit tests on a spring project on Maven build or install.

The test class in src/main/test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
        "classpath:mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml", 
        "classpath:appContext.xml",
        "classpath:databaseContext.xml"})
    public class Test {
        @Autowired
        private EventService evtService;

        @org.junit.Test
        public void test1(){
            List<String> eventNames = evtService.getEventNames();
            Assert.assertTrue(eventNames.size() > 0);
        }
    }
```

In the POM:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <parallel>classes</parallel>
        <threadCount>10</threadCount>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

When I run the Test class from eclipse with Run as -> JUnit test it works fine, but when I run Maven Install for example I get:

```
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Concurrency config is parallel='classes', perCoreThreadCount=true, threadCount=10, useUnlimitedThreads=false
There are no tests to run.

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Versions: JUnit: 4.11; Spring: 3.2.3.RELEASE

Comment: which version of Junit is declared as dependency in your pom.xml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your mentioning in your quesiton is correct `The test class in src/main/test` than this is the simple problem, cause test have to be located into `/src/test/java` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Do you inherit this POM from some parent?Because this configuration of the `surefire-plugin` is probably in your parent, causing your tests to be skipped.

```
<configuration>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
</configuration>
```

So you need either to remove the `skipTests` property from your parent or explicitly allow tests in child project.

Comment: The POM has no parent. Also I tried 'mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip=false' and still get "There are no tests to run."

Comment: Also adding '<skipTests>false</skipTests>' to surefire conf didn't worked.

Comment: The try what @khmarbaise mentioned in this answer